# How do I list all C programs which starts with abc and the 4th and 5th letters are either 1 or 2

Tags: files, wildcards

Can I do something like `ls abc[0|1][0|1].c`?

Comment: Close, try `ls abc[12][12].c`. :-) (assuming you want the fourth and fifth letters to be `1` or `2` as stated in the title) Also, are more letters permitted before the `.c` extension? (e.g., `abc11xyz.c`)? Then you need to add a wildcard: `ls abc[12][12]*.c`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The filename globbing pattern for "either 1 or 2" is `[12]`.  This will match a single character which is either 1 or 2.

To match all `.c` files whose names start with `abc` and continues with a 1 or a 2, you would use

```
abc[12].c
```

To allow a fifth character which is *also* a 1 or a 2, you would use

```
abc[12][12].c
```

A `?` will match any single character and `*` will match *any number of characters*, so `abc[12][12]???.c` would match `abc11xxx.c` but not `abc11xxxx.c` whereas `abc[12][12]*.c` would.

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you for the explanation. :)

Comment: @AvishekPaul Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).